# Сalculate polygon centroids with 'point on surface' function

Tags: qgis, centroids, minidump

I want to calculate centroid coordinates X_center and Y_center for every polygon in layer so that in case polygon has not simple shape (e.g. with holes or like in the picture below) centroid will be in the polygon anyway:

[image]

I found 'point on surface' function in QGIS, that returns a point guaranteed to lie on the surface of a geometry. BUT When trying to calculate coordinates with the function, dump happens, although qgis shows output preview correctly -

[image]

I found similar [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72112/qgis-i-would-like-to-get-a-single-point-from-a-polygon-centroid-if-within-the-po) but the following answer implicates new point layer creation, that is useless for me - I want to get centroid coordinates in the same layer.

Interesting, when creating virtual field - it calculates, I can even pick the polygon and see coordinates, but when opening attribute table, qgis crushes.

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: Which QGIS version and platform are you using? Does it crash when you finish entering the expression or when you click `OK` in the Field Calculator?

Comment: QGIS 2.18.12, dump crashes when I clicking OK in the Field Calculator

Comment: Does it still crash if you create a **virtual field** or changing the field type (you can always copy over the values to a new `real` field)?

Comment: Interesing, it calculates, but when opening attribute table, it crashes!

Comment: I've added some info in my question about virtual field

Comment: It worked perfectly for me. Thanks to your question and very useful explanation of the problem, I just learn how to calculate in one simple step something I was doing in many steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like something in your geometry is causing the issue. I'd check your geometry validity, and also open a bug report for qgis and attach your original dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similarly doubt, but I used Python to store the centroid in a new shapefile.
See my question. I think it will help you:

[Saving centroid with attribute fields in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/257269/saving-centroid-with-attribute-fields-in-pyqgis/257307#257307)